# trying to make my own activation function

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to make my own activation function which is f(X) = 2/pi * arctan(x) when x<0 and x/1+abs(x) when x >=0
Iam trying to do it in keras and i used this code :

```
from keras import backend as k
def fun8(y):
    return ((2/k.pi) * k.atan2(y)) if y<0 else (y/1+k.abs(y))
```

and i used it in my model :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2),
             input_shape=input_shape, kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(fun8))
 model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2), 
kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(fun8))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2), kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(fun8))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))



model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

and it gave me that error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Comment: Indeed, you cannot do conditional assignment with tensors. Try `((2/k.pi) * k.atan2(y)) * (y<0) + (y/(1+k.abs(y))) * (y > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the expression `if y<0`.  `y<0` is a vector of Booleans; `if` requires a scalar argument.  What you're trying to do is a filter type of operation; you can't do it with this simple syntax.  Instead, you'll need to use `y<0` *as a tensor*, and adjust you expression accordingly.  @Marat already gave you one possibility (although missing the "equals" clause on one side or the other).